# HTML Table display issue while generating PDF using renderAsPdf in vf page?

Tags: visualforce, pdf, table

I am trying to display multiple html tables in vf page using apex:repeat using renderAsPdf.
Issue: Some times the HTML table displays inappropriate way at the end of pdf page like below image :

[image]

does anyone face this weird issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding something like this to CSS

```
table { page-break-after:auto }
tr    { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }
td    { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }
thead { display: table-row-group; }
tfoot { display:table-footer-group }
```

Comment: I already tried that before but did not work, I found another solution for this by using "-fs-table-paginate: paginate" in <table> tag and It worked for me.

Comment: cool, write it as an answer yourself, so the question can be closed